# Wrapper for std::queue emplace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, variadic-templates

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 and trying to create a wrapper for std::queue which adds thread safety and a few other features.  I'm having trouble creating a wrapper function for emplace.  I suspect it's due to the way variadic templates are emulated, but I"m not sure how to fix it.

```
template <typename T>
class MyQueue
{
public:
   template <class... Args>             // line 20
   void emplace(Args&&... args)
   {
      mQueue.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   }
private:
   std::queue<T> mQueue;
};
```

This code gives me a bunch of syntax errors.

@ line 20:

- C2011: '' : 'enum' type redefinition
- C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '...'
- C2332: 'class' : missing tag name

@ line 21:

- C2059: syntax error : '...'
- C2065: 'Args' : undeclared identifier

Is there any clean way to tap into the underlying queue's `emplace` function?  I'm not doing anything performance critical so if it ends up being more trouble than it's worth I'll just force callers to use `push`.

Any solutions must be with VC++11 - switching platforms or compilers is not an option for me.

Comment: The code itself looks OK, but we need to see the error message and maybe the code calling it.

Comment: Added a few errors.  It's even generating errors for stuff further down in the file that go away when emplace is commented out - like it can't match a curly brace or something.

Comment: Are you using VS2012 with [November 2012 Compiler CTP](http://aka.ms/vc-ctp)? Your code compiles fine here with both gcc and clang.

Comment: @Uflex - thanks for the tip.  I had installed the CTP but never realized that I needed to activate it in the project settings.  That did the trick.

Comment: As an aside, `std::queue` that ships with VS2012 (and the CTP) doesn't have variardic `emplace` yet.  Your code will work with the one-argument version of `emplace` they ship with (among the most useless things ever), and fail if you pass more than 1 argument...

Comment: Where's the emulation? And where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Yakk - I'm not finding that to be the case.  See my answer for an example with with >1 arguments.  It looks like the macro for emplace generates overloads for up to 5 arguments.  I feel like I read somewhere that you can up that to 10 arguments but it increases your compile time by quite a bit.

Comment: @zmb great!  I am happy to be mistaken here.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this to work by changing the Platform Toolset to the Nov 2012 CTP in the project settings.  As others pointed out - the code itself was correct.  See below for a simple example.

MyQueue.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class MyQueue
{
public:
    template <class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args);
private:
    std::queue<T> mQueue;
};

template <typename T>
template <class... Args>
void MyQueue<T>::emplace(Args&&... args)
{
    mQueue.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "MyQueue.h"

struct Test
{
    int mA, mB;
    Test(int a, int b) : mA(a), mB(b) { }
};

int main()
{
    MyQueue<Test> q;
    q.emplace(1, 1);
    q.emplace(2, 2);
    q.emplace(3, 3);

    return 0;
}
```